# DPDK setup issue : eth_virtio_pci_init(): Failed to init PCI device

Tags: ubuntu, dpdk

I am getting following error while running hello world program on VM created by Virt-Manager using ubuntu server 22.04.3 LTS (Manual server installation).

```
root@dpdk:~/dpdk-22.11.1/build/examples# ./dpdk-helloworld  
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4                                            
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1  
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK  
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket  
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'  
EAL: VFIO support initialized  
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_virtio (1af4:1041) device: 0000:01:00.0   (socket -1)  
eth_virtio_pci_init(): Failed to init PCI device  
EAL: Requested device 0000:01:00.0 cannot be used  
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_virtio (1af4:1041) device: 0000:02:00.0   (socket -1)  
eth_virtio_pci_init(): Failed to init PCI device  
EAL: Requested device 0000:02:00.0 cannot be used  
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_em (8086:10d3) device: 0000:03:00.0 (socket -1)  
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_em (8086:10d3) device: 0000:04:00.0 (socket -1)  
hello from core 1  
hello from core 2  
hello from core 0  
hello from core 3  

root@dpdk:~/dpdk-22.11.1/build/examples# dpdk-devbind.py -s
    
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver 
 
============================================      
0000:03:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e,vfio-pci      
0000:04:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e,vfio-pci

Network devices using kernel driver  

===================================  
0000:01:00.0 'Virtio network device 1041' if=enp1s0 drv=virtio-pci unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*  
0000:02:00.0 'Virtio network device 1041' if=enp2s0 drv=virtio-pci unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*

Misc (rawdev) devices using kernel driver

=========================================

0000:07:00.0 'Virtio block device 1042' drv=virtio-pci unused=vfio-
pci,uio_pci_generic

No 'Regex' devices detected

===========================

root@dpdk:~/dpdk-22.11.1/build/examples#
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Pallav Singh